# Custom field not sourced to work order SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: javascript, netsuite, production, suitescript

Here is my code snippet for creating a work order:

```
var TO = record.create({
  type: 'workorder',
  isDynamic: true
});

TO.setValue({
  fieldId: 'customform',
  value: '80'
});

TO.setValue({
  fieldId: 'subsidiary',
  value: 1
});

TO.setValue({
  fieldId: 'location',
  value: 1
});

TO.setValue({
  fieldId: 'assemblyitem',
  value: item
});

TO.setValue({
  fieldId: 'quantity',
  value: qtytobuild
});

var newWO = TO.save({
  ignoreMandatoryFields: true
});
```

The work order is created with the right quantity to build. The component list (item sublist) is correct in terms of items and quantities. So nothing to worry about there. But, I have a custom field on the item record that is sourced to the work order component sublist (to a transaction line field). It works fine if I manually create the work order, but if I do it with my script it is not sourced. I have tried to set isDynamic:false with the same result.

Does anybody have an idea of what could be causing this?

Comment: To be clear the sourced value is not present after saving the work order. Is that correct?
What is the script type being called? Are there any subsidiary restrictions on the item or on the user who invokes the script?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the enableSourcing option to true on the save (this defaults to false.

var newWO = TO.save({
ignoreMandatoryFields: true,
enableSourcing: true
});

Comment: Hi, Thank you. I tried it out now and it didn't solved it... Thank you for your response!

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding correctly.  Are you saying you have a sourced field on the item record that should update when you create this workorder?

Comment: You may need to load that item record to get that sourced field to populate with data.

Comment: Yes, it should be sources from an item in the component list to the work order component list. So I never load the component list from the assembly, Netsuite puts the components automatically on the work order when I choose assembly.